# Kafka topic not being deleted

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 0.10.0.1. There are 3 brokers in the cluster. I issued delete command to delete nearly 10 topics which were not getting used since a month. I had checked, there are no consumers registered on those topics, nor were their log sizes increasing.

However, it's been more than 5 hours and those topics haven't yet been deleted. They are just marked for deletion. What can be the reason?

Comment: haven't deleted means from Kafka-logs ?? or else any dashboard kind of thing?

Comment: yes from Kafka logs. Because whenever I hit topic list command I see all of them there marked as deleted, but just there

Comment: Can u check your delete_topics path in zookeeper using ls /admin/delete_topics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default in 0.10, `delete.topic.enable` is `false`. To be able to delete topics, you need to set this to `true` in the broker properties file.

Note that starting from 1.0.0, this is now enabled by default.

Comment: OMG really? I saw in documentation it was mentioned true as default! Hence I didn't try turning it on/off

Comment: The Kafka website shows the documentation for the latest version. You can however select previous versions at the top of the page. The link to the 0.10 version is : http://kafka.apache.org/0100/documentation.html

Comment: Hello, that was great help. One of the 3 Kafka brokers didn't have that setting. I set it to true on that one and restarted it and immediately all marked topics got deleted! :-)

Answer (score 2):

extending to Mickael answer

In Kafka 0.10, default value of delete.topic.enable is false.

When using the command-line tools to delete a topic, a Zookeeper node requests that the deletion is created. Under normal circumstances, this is executed by the cluster immediately. However, the command-line tool has no way of knowing whether topic deletion is enabled in the cluster. As a result, it will request deletion of topics regardless, which can result in a surprise if deletion is disabled.

Topics are requested for deletion by creating a Zookeeper node as a child under /admin/delete_topic, which is named with the topic name. a new thread will invoke and check topic deletion is enabled or not. if enabled it will delete all logs and paths in zookeeper

if deletion is not enabled we have to manually delete all the configs of topic

steps to remove topic manually :

1. Shut down all brokers in the cluster
2. Remove the Zookeeper path /brokers/topics/TOPICNAME from the Kafka cluster path. Note that this node has child nodes that must be deleted first.
3. Remove the partition directories from the log directories on each broker. These will be named TOPICNAME-NUM, where NUM is the partition ID.
4. Restart all brokers