# Kafka fails on start due to topic not being loaded

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I have setup Kafka server and a zookeeper in a windows machine with help from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os). I was successfully able to setup a topic - MTETest as in below log, produce and consume messages to this topic.

On trying to stop and start Kafka and Zookeeper using the batch files that came with installation in a adminitrator command prompt, I am facing a problem that the kafka server is unable to start with below message -

> [2017-11-30 21:26:24,601] ERROR There was an error in one of the
>   threads during logs loading: java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   C:SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\MTETest-0\00000000000000000000.timeindex:
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.  (kafka.log.LogManager) [2017-11-30 21:26:24,603] FATAL
>   [Kafka Server 0], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to
>   shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer) java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   C:SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\MTETest-0\00000000000000000000.timeindex:
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.
>
> at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)  at
>   kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$loadSegmentFiles$3.apply(Log.scala:318)    at
>   kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$loadSegmentFiles$3.apply(Log.scala:279)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
>     at kafka.log.Log.loadSegmentFiles(Log.scala:279)    at
>   kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:383)     at
>   kafka.log.Log.(Log.scala:186)   at
>   kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:1609)  at
>   kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:172)
>     at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:57)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [2017-11-30 21:26:24,606]
>   WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt
>   index found, index file
>   (C:\Source\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\MTETestTopic-0\00000000000000000000.index)
>   has non-zero size but the last offset is 0 which is no larger than the
>   base offset 0.}. deleting
>   C:\Source\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\MTETestTopic-0\00000000000000000000.timeindex,
>   C:\Source\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\MTETestTopic-0\00000000000000000000.index,
>   and
>   C:\Source\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\MTETestTopic-0\00000000000000000000.txnindex
>   and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log) [2017-11-30 21:26:24,609] INFO
>   [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2017-11-30
>   21:26:24,613] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread.
>   (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread) [2017-11-30 21:26:24,615] WARN
>   Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index
>   found, index file
>   (C:\Source\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1__consumer_offsets-0\00000000000000000000.index)
>   has non-zero size but the last offset is 0 which is no larger than the
>   base offset 0.}. deleting
>   C:\Source\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1__consumer_offsets-0\00000000000000000000.timeindex,
>   C:\Source\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1__consumer_offsets-0\00000000000000000000.index,
>   and
>   C:\Source\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1\SourceKafkakafka_2.11-0.11.0.1__consumer_offsets-0\00000000000000000000.txnindex
>   and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log) [2017-11-30 21:26:24,616] INFO
>   Session: 0x1600d98747a0001 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
>   [2017-11-30 21:26:24,623] INFO EventThread shut down for session:
>   0x1600d98747a0001 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [2017-11-30
>   21:26:24,625] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shut down completed
>   (kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2017-11-30 21:26:24,626] FATAL Exiting
>   Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable) [2017-11-30 21:26:24,628]
>   INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

I have tried changing the setting - delete.topic.enable to true as per suggestion in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353514/kafka-topic-not-being-deleted) in kafka server.properties, but it did not help. Also, I did not open the topic or its related files manually. Anyone faced this issue, please help. Is this problem specific to windows?

It loads successfully when I delete the topic and its related physical folders that are created by Kafka, but it is not the right thing. Please suggest the correct solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @LearnAndShare. Also me have this issue with Kafka 1.0.0 in a WIndows environment. Do you have updates? Did you write a bug report on the Kafka support?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message:

```
 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

you have another process already using this file and it is preventing Kafka from starting. See https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows for finding the process

Comment: Thanks, It is helpful to find the process which is holding the topic file required by Kafka but this issue is reported by one more colleague as well, so it is probably, a bug in Kafka+Windows environment. On calling the kafka stop command file this issue should not occur otherwise this cannot be used for production deployments.

Comment: Kafka is known to have some issues with Windows, see: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#os